# How to work with mulitple annotation folder in latest version of darkaonline/l5-swagger?

Tags: laravel-8, openapi, l5-swagger, darkaonlinel5-swagger

It was working perfectly with multiple annotation folders in laravel 8.0, forgot the minor version of l5-swagger. Later when I do `composer update` and darkoline get updated to `^8.3` version. Now, its trying to make documentation(#SchemaRef) out of each file stored inside the folder. I do have following configuration

```
/*
* Absolute paths to directory containing the swagger annotations are stored.
*/
annotations' => [
   base_path('app'),
   base_path('Modules'),
]
```

In my case I do have  following error

```
 ErrorException 
 Skipping unknown \CreateRolesTable
```

Here CretaetRolesTable is a migration file inside Modules folder, no swagger related annotation exists in CreateRolesTable file and neither this name is being used as #ref.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the anonymous function in `CreateRolesTable` file.

```php
return new class extends Migration
```

For more information check the official documentation.([see more](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#migration-structure))

Comment: Tried but that does not work ... actually Swagger generating error for each files in Modules folder.  Thanks for your answer